# PHP if have image display image, if else text

Tags: php, theme-options

I'm a front-end web developer struggling with some theme option support. I am struggling to write a simple function in my header.php which allows me to do the following:

"if user uploads an image, use the image. If else use 'logo_text' and echo output. If user doesnt upload image or logo_text use default of 'My Site'"

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get started? I don't know where to begin for this one.

```
    <li class="name">
      <!-- Logo Text -->
      <h1><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/home" title="<? echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
        <? $novus_logo_text = get_option('novus_logo_text'); echo $novus_logo_text; ?>
      </a></h1>
      <!-- Logo Image -->
      <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/home" title="<? echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
        <? $novus_logo_upload = get_option('novus_logo_upload'); echo '<img class=\"logo"\ src="'.$novus_logo_upload.'" width=\"100%"\ />'; ?>
      </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: What would option hold if there is no upload? `if ( empty( $novus_logo_upload ) {} else {}` would probably do it. Note that pure PHP questions might make more sense on [so], we mostly have stuff specific to WordPress here. :)

Comment: This is for a wordpress site, which is why I am asking :)! I am using ProPanel from codecanyon to handle the theme-options functions. If they do not have an upload it should default to their input for the logo_text, "My Site Name Here". If they fail to do both it defaults to std="My Site" in the function.
Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question on stackoverflow, and got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193409/php-if-have-image-display-image-if-else-text) from @cmorrissey. Credit goes to him for this code.

```
    <?php if($novus_logo_upload = get_option('novus_logo_upload')){ ?>
      <!-- Logo Image -->
        <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/home" title="<? echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
        <? echo '<img class=\"logo"\ src="'.$novus_logo_upload.'" width=\"100%"\ />'; ?>
        </a>
      <?php } else if($novus_logo_text = get_option('novus_logo_text')){ ?>
        <!-- Logo Text -->
        <h1><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/home" title="<? echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
        <? echo $novus_logo_text; ?>
        </a></h1>
      <?php } else { ?>
        <!-- Default -->
        <h1><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/home" title="<? echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"> My Site </a></h1>
      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Right on the money, but I would recommend changing the line `<? echo '<img class=\"logo"\ src="'.$novus_logo_upload.'" width=\"100%"\ />'; ?>` to `<img class="logo" src="<?php echo $novus_logo_upload; ?>" width="100%" />`
Echoing markup is bad, mkay?

Comment: You should link to that answers and credit the author